# Как спарсить динамические значения?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4, lxml

Изучая парсинг поставил себе задачу спарсить данные с сайта https://www.binance.com/ru/markets ради интереса попытался вытащить имя по типу : BNB/ BTC но но почему то выходит исключения

```
ic| name: 'BNB'

Traceback (most recent call last):
    name = item.find('div', class_="css-7ea2d1").find('div').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

при том что название вытащила как видно по icecream , а вторая проблема возникла когда захотел вытянуть значение т.е. колонку последняя цена в консоль выдаёт что там значения '-'
именно такое , а не цифры , вот код

```
ua = UserAgent()
URL = 'https://www.binance.com/ru/markets'

response = requests.get(URL, ua.random).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

Block = soup.find_all('div', class_="css-4cffwv")

for item in Block:
    price = item.find('div', class_="css-10nf7hq").find('div')
    price2 = item.find('div', class_="css-10nf7hq").find('div').next
```

и у меня закралось сомнение что с помощью bs4 и lxml нельзя динамические значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Изучая парсинг поставил себе задачу спарсить данные с сайта

Плохо усвоили парсинг. Прежде чем парсить что-то, убедись, что нужную информацию нельзя получить используя public-api:

- https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo;
- https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price;
- https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT;
- https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h&limit=24